# Mi aplicación android guarda los datos en firebase con el abecedario cuando la descargo desde la play store y desde el pc si guardan normal?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, google-play, google-play-console

Tengo todos mis objetos bien nombrados pero cuando guardo solo aparecen estos,
ademas cuando la instalo desde el pc guarda todo bien pero cuando lo hago al descargarla desde la play store solo me guarda asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues la verdad, me gustaría poder responderte algo, pero no entiendo tu pregunta. No encuentro sentido al título ni a la descripción. Por favor, redacta de nuevo la pregunta y trata de ser más específico con tu problema, incluyendo código suficiente para poder entender y responder a tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido! Coincido con SuperG280, he entrado a tu pregunta para intentarla responder pero me faltaría un poco de código, algun pantallazo de firebase quizá... Si puedes ampliarla casi seguro que obtienes la solución. Un saludo!

Comment: Ya añadi los pantallazos.

Comment: @Juangonzalez bienvenido por favor no agregues el código como imagen sino como texto

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Mi aplicación android guarda los datos en firebase con el abecedario cuando la descargo de la play store y desde el pc si guardan normal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/325294/mi-aplicaci%c3%b3n-android-guarda-los-datos-en-firebase-con-el-abecedario-cuando-la-d)